# Only receives one cookie in fetch response on Android but not on iOS

Tags: android, react-native, cookies, fetch, expo

When I send a POST fetch request to my website to login it all works on iOS. The fetch response set-cookie have all the cookies I need to proceed and make future requests. The problem is on Android I only receive one cookie in set-cookie, even though there is more. It seems like it gets cut and I can't seem to access the raw response.

My fetch code:

```
    const myRequest = new Request('MYURL', 
      {method: 'POST', body: parameters,
         headers: {
             "Referer": 'MYURL.com/login',
             'Origin': 'MYURL',
             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }});
    fetch(myRequest)
      .then(
        function(response) {
          try {
            console.log("JSON RESPONSE: " + response.json());
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));

            console.log(response.headers.get('Content-Type'));
            console.log(response.headers.get('Date'));

          } catch(err) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + err);
          }
        }
    )
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Fetch Error', err);
    });
```

I know that android gets correctly logged in cause the server redirects me to the menu page and also recognizes the clients personal ID.

Here is the response from iOS(the one that works):

> "set-cookie": "session=CENSORED; Domain=.MYURL; Path=/; HttpOnly, clientID=123; expires=Thu, 07-Nov-2019 09:27:20 GMT; domain=.MYURL; path=/",

Perfect response. Everything works.

Here is the response from android:

> "set-cookie": "clientID=123; expires=Thu, 07-Nov-2019 09:34:00 GMT; domain=.MYURL; path=/",

I've tried for several days to understand the problem but to no avail. I've tried to test cookies without httponly to see if that was the error but no.

I hope some experienced react-native users can shine light on this problem. I haven't experienced it before when I created native apps for android and IOS. Only with react-native. :-(

I hope to get to this to work since I would rather avoid using native code for this small part.

EDIT: Tested fetch function with reddit login api and same problem occurs. Only 1 cookie in response set-cookio on Android but all cookies shown on iOS.

Comment: did you ever find the answer to this? experiencing the same struggle here

Comment: @Return-1 Hey. I ended up sending the cookies through json response. Couldn't solve it otherwise. That may not solve your problem if you don't have control over the backend, though.

Comment: which is exactly my case. I managed solving it as described here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23005. waiting for the issue to be resolved

Comment: Hi. Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the official documents of React Native and MDN:

1. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

The problem here is `fetch` won't send or receive any cookie from server by default. So you have to enable it by add `credentials`. And there are some libraries that can help you manage cookies:

- https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies

Comment: I added 'credentials': 'include' to my fetch request but it changes nothing. I still got the same response on iOS and android. iOS still works fine and android still doesn't work.

Comment: And how does it explain why I still receive the cookies properly on iOS but not on android? And it's not like I don't receive any. I still receive one cookie but only 1 on android. Thanks for the links, though!

Comment: This must be a bug of RN. Which version of RN are you using? I found a report here and it's not fixed: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21795